# How can I modify the filename suffixes of uploaded files in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, filenames

I was wondering if it is possible to modify the way WordPress handles image uploads.  If I upload an image now, the default filenames for the various sizes include the dimensions, something like the following:
`image-100x100.jpg`, `image-300x300.jpg`, `image-600x600.jpg`, and `image.jpg`.

While this may be useful in some cases, I need these file names to be a bit more versatile, something like the following: 
`image-thumb.jpg`, `image-medium.jpg`, `image-large.jpg`, and `image.jpg`.

Does anyone have any ideas how I could accomplish this?  Thank you for reading.  As always, any ideas or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: I don't know for certain, but this may be deeply rooted into WP's core. What do you need this for? Maybe you can work around it using a set of `mod_rewrite` instructions?

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I am working on a client website, and there are some images throughout the page that they want to be able to replace.  I am using a plugin that will allow you to replace existing images through the Media section.  However, if they don't upload an image that is the same ratio, then the filenames will be off. For example, if the image they are trying to replace is 100x100 pixels, and they upload one that gets resized to 100x90px, then there will be a broken image, as the filenames aren't the same. I hope this makes sense, haha. Again, thanks for the reply.

Comment: is using post images (which you can resize automagically by defining thumbnail sizes in functions.php) out of the question?

Comment: Would post images be able to autoresize any image the user uploads and keep multiple sizes in the uploads folder?  If so, I don't see why that would be out of the question.

Comment: Yes, since 3.0 I believe. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size

Comment: Wow, thank you for pointing me in the right direction.  This looks very promising.  How did I miss this before? Haha.

Comment: No problem. I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to use Wordpress' native [post images](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Image_and_File_Attachments), for which you can define resize dimensions using [`add_image_size`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size). I think this is a 3.0+ feature.