# How to change the filename suffix of uploaded files in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need Wordpress to generate filenames like `image-small.jpg` and `image-medium.jpg` instead of `image-576x248.jpg` and `image-992x427.jpg`. Is it possible?

It would also be ok if the height could be removed from the suffix (`image-576.jpg`, `image-992.jpg`).

Comment: Refer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9447940/how-can-i-modify-the-filename-suffixes-of-uploaded-files-in-wordpress)

Comment: @RakhiPrajapati the answer on the question you mentioned doesn't solve my problem. I already have image sizes set up, but I only set the width, this way I don't know what the suffix will be.